# Multiplication on the command line using argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, argparse, multiplication

I have to write some arithmetic script.
The script should be launched like this:

```
$ python name_script.py 2 + 2
$ python name_script.py 2 * 2
```

To enter data in one line, I use argparse.
But I have a problem with multiplication (`*`) and division (`/`), argparse doesn't perform them as mathematical operations.
How to make argparse perceive input (`*`) as multiplication?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Python or argparse: you *must* escape `*` on the command line, otherwise your shell will expand it as a wildcard. Python can’t do anything to prevent this, since it happens *before* Python is launched. In other words: there is no way to meet the stated requirements.

Comment: @RonnyOutside : You can detect this kind of bug easily if you do a `set -x` in your shell before running the Python command.

Comment: My script expects three input parameters: digit, arithmetic operation (+, -, * or /), digit. And in the form, as indicated in the example. Is it really unrealizable?

Comment: argparse doesn't do any math; the rest of your script might.  But you haven't shown that code, nor any results or errors.  And check `sys.argv` if the input of '*' seems funny.